# react native text input with required asterisk symbol similar to material ui

Tags: react-native

Please share samples in react native
text input with required asterisk symbol similar to material ui
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qFxU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have used `"react-native-paper": "4.9.2"` below code works fine in this version.

```
<TextInput
  mode="flat"
  label={
  <Text>
       Label
       <Text style={{color: 'red'}}> *</Text>
  </Text>
  }
  placeholder="Type something"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you prefer, create a component for that:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

export default function InputLabel({ label, style={}, required=false }) {
    return (
        <Text style={style}>
            {label}
            {required && <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}> *</Text>}
        </Text>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way i found is :

```
<TextInput
placeholder={placeholder}
>
<Text style={{ position: 'absolute', left: 10, color: Colors.Red }}><Text style={{ opacity: 0 }}>{placeholder}{''} </Text>*</Text>
</TextInput>
```

make sure you apply same text style to the placeholder and text as children of the text input

hide when you enter some text, else if it will still visible when you enter text

Answer (score -1):

Use [react-native-paper](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper)

```
<TextInput
  label='Password '
  mode='outlined' 
  value={this.state.text} 
  onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
  underlineColor='transparent' 
  theme={...}
>
```

More detail [Here](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/text-input.html)

Comment: in react native paper there is no props required . and highlighting asterisk with red color.

Comment: For text like `Required *` there is a prop called `label` and use `mode='outlined'` and for validation, there are rules for it to validate

Comment: please share some examples